# LDMIA instruction not working correctly on external SRAM in cortex M4

Tags: gcc, memory, arm, ram, cortex-m

I am using STM32L486ZG board in thumb mode. I am running a simple bare-metal application without any RTOS. I have external SRAM connected to the board using FSM. The external SRAM is located at address 0x60000000. The system is initialized and running at 72MHz (i have tried this issue with frequency from 18-80 MHz) now in my main function i have following code:

```
int main(){
    asm volatile (
            "push {r0}\n"
            "mov r0, #0x60000000\n"
            "add r0, #0x400\n"
            "stmdb r0!, {r1-r12}\n"
            "ldmia r0!, {r1-r12}\n"
            "pop {r0}\n"
            );
}
```

According to this code no register should be changed after this main function has executed, but that's not the case after the following instruction

```
ldmia r0!, {r1-r12}
```

i.e. `r9` is not correct after execution. `stmdb` instruction is working correctly but `ldmia` is not loading the data correctly. I have verified this by viewing the contents from memory.

This issue is persistent with any arguments in the `ldmia` instruction: the 9th register is always affected.

**Explanation:**
Lets say I am debugging this code and the next instruction to execute is this:

```
stmdb r0!, {r1-r12}
```

after stepping up all these registers have been saved in the memory and value of `r0` is `0x600003d0`

the contents of memory:

```
0x600003D0  00000000 40021008 0000000C  .......@....
0x600003DC  40000000 00000000 00000000  ...@........
0x600003E8  20017FEC 00000000 00000000  ì.. ........
0x600003F4  00000000 00000000 00000000  ............
```

content of the registers:

```
r0  0x600003d0
r1  0x00000000
r2  0x40021008
r3  0x0000000c
r4  0x40000000
r5  0x00000000
r6  0x00000000
r7  0x20017fec
r8  0x00000000
r9  0x00000000
r10 0x00000000
r11 0x00000000  
r12 0x00000000
```

this shows that all the registers are successfully saved in the memory. Now i step the next instruction

```
ldmia r0!, {r1-r12}
```

after this
these are the contents of registers:

```
r0  0x60000400
r1  0x00000000
r2  0x40021008
r3  0x0000000c
r4  0x40000000
r5  0x00000000
r6  0x00000000
r7  0x20017fec
r8  0x00000000
r9  0x555555d5
r10 0x00000000
r11 0x00000000
r12 0x00000000
```

**as you can see all the registers are restored except `r9` which oddly has its value "pop"ed from `0x60000000` instead of `0x600003F0`.**

Any idea what could be causing this issue. I am using Jlink to write into flash.

P.S. This issue doesn't occur when the registers are saved to onchip SRAM as opposed to external SRAM;

**edit**
if the instruction

```
ldmia r0!, {r1-r12}
```

is split into two parts like:

```
ldmia r0!, {r1-r6}
ldmia r0!, {r7-r12}
```

then all the registers are restored successfully

Comment: " am running a simple bare-metal application without any RTOS. I have external SRAM connected to the board using FSM"... what is a **FSM**

Comment: Are the registers beyond the 9th always correct? The fact that it apparently goes awry across a 32-byte boundary smells quite a bit like either the address lines aren't wired up right or the memory controller isn't configured properly (particularly with respect to AHB burst splitting and/or timing).

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes they are always correct only the 9th is the faulty one.

Comment: @Notlikethat If it is a 32-byte boundary issue then why `r10` `r11` etc at read correctly

Comment: If they _weren't_ then it might suggest some find of address wrapping issue - as it is, it sounds like a "slap a logic analyser on the pins and check the timings" type problem, coupled with a careful cross-checking of the FSMC configuration against the SRAM datasheet (assuming that your board layout is sound, of course). Probably more of an [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) thing than a programming one.

Comment: Can you try putting known values in R8 to R12 and storing them and then loading them. It's not conclusive from your code that the problem only lies with R9, as the registers might already be 0.

Comment: @RealtimeRik I have also tried adding known value and problem only lie within `r9`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read the STM32L4xx6xx Silicon Limitations. Section 2.2.4 Read burst access of nine words or more is not supported by FMC. ( DocID026121 Rev 4 ) available from ST.

"CPU read burst access equal to or more than 9 registers to FMC returns corrupted data
starting from the 9th read word. These bursts can only be generated by Cortex®-M4 CPU
and not by the other masters (i.e not by DMA).
This issue occurs when the stack is remapped on the external memory on the FMC and
POP operations are performed with 9 or more registers.
This also occurs when LDM/VLDM operations are used with 9 or more registers."

Comment: It also provides the work around. I only put a snippet here.

Comment: Thanks This really helped