# LDMIA instruction results in corrupt register data

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gdb, cortex-m

I'm attempting to run a compiled program on a ARM Cortex-M3 bare metal. Before the system even reaches the application code, an odd error blows the program counter away and errors out.

Before the instruction, the registers are observed to be:

```
r0             0x0  0
r1             0x1  1
r2             0x0  0
r3             0x2  2
r4             0x18564  99684
r5             0x18418  99352
r6             0x0  0
r7             0x0  0
r8             0x8311   33553
r9             0x0  0
r10            0x0  0
r11            0x0  0
r12            0xc84404 13124612
sp             0x7ffe0  0x7ffe0
lr             0x80df   32991
pc             0x8380   0x8380
```

The following instruction is executed nominally:

```
0x829c <__call_exitprocs+112>:  ldmia.w sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, pc}
```

And the registers being read explode. It also sends the program counter way off effectively terminating the program.

```
...
r3             0x2  2
r4             0xffffffff   4294967295
r5             0xffffffff   4294967295
r6             0xffffffff   4294967295
r7             0xffffffff   4294967295
r8             0xffffffff   4294967295
r9             0xffffffff   4294967295
r10            0xffffffff   4294967295
r11            0x0  0
...
pc             0xfffffffe   0xfffffffe
```

I've read [a similar issue on stack overfflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265112/ldmia-instruction-not-working-correctly-on-external-sram-in-cortex-m4), but it doesn't seem to be the direct issue that I'm facing here. [The ATMEL documentation for this board](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-6430-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3U4-SAM3U2-SAM3U1_Datasheet.pdf) doesn't specify a limitation on number of internal registers read at once on a quick glance.

Any thoughts on the problem and, if possible, a workaround in gcc to prevent it?

Comment: That `ldmia` loads from the stack, and you haven't shown what's on the stack. The instruction may very well be operating correctly, if the data on the stack is corrupted.

Comment: the thumb instruction does not permit that many registers but the thumb2 (armv7m) extension does.  The disassembler assuming that is what your text is from, would not have shown all those registers otherwise.  And as you pointed out yourself, the pc is bad, so the ldmia is modifying the pc, and that pc as pointed out by Jester is probably bad on the stack.  dump the stack before the instruction and see what it contains.

Comment: Only the  `sp 0x7ffe0` is important before the instruction, not sure why you posted other registers. Didn't you want to do instead a "push to stack" `stmia`? If not, then the code ahead of this must already put enough values into the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction (and its effect) are absolutely correct. But the `sp` value **before** this instruction is absolutely wrong. Your chip has no RAM memory on that address. In fact - it probably has no memory at all at this address. See page 32 of the manual (with the memory map).

http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-6430-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3U4-SAM3U2-SAM3U1_Datasheet.pdf

Your `sp` should be somewhere within SRAM, so above `0x20000000`. The value you have - `0x7ffe0` is somewhere in the "Boot memory" region. If you want to find the problem, find out why `sp` has invalid value.